# Disabling dialog OK button MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

How do I disable MFC dialog OK button?
This code:
`CWnd* fieldOK = pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK);

 fieldOK->EnableWindow(FALSE);`
causes exception "*Access violation reading location...*"
 in line `ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));` of function `CWnd::EnableWindow(BOOL bEnable)` in `winnocc.cpp` from `mfc90d.dll`
In this time focus is on another control.
What's can be wrong?

Thanks for help.

[EDITED]

```
bool CSCalcNormCell::OnSelectionChanged( CWnd* pDlg, int type, int page, UINT ctrl_id ) 
{ 
  DDX_DataBox(pDX.get(), IDC_WORKSHOP_COMBO, ws_code); 
  if (!CInfactoryPriceAdapter::CanEditPricesForWorkshop( ws_code )) 
  { 
    CWnd* fieldOK = pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK); 
    fieldOK->EnableWindow(FALSE); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    CWnd* fieldOK = pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK); 
    fieldOK->EnableWindow(TRUE); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why would wouldn't be able to do it.  If I take a regular CDialog and I do an init like this:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog() {
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    CWnd *okbtn = GetDlgItem( IDOK );
    if ( okbtn ) {
        okbtn->EnableWindow( FALSE );
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

it disables the button just fine.  Perhaps something else is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/122489

> **How to Disable Default Pushbutton Handling for MFC Dialog**
>
> Although default button (pushbutton) support is recommended, you might
>   want to disable or modify the standard implementation in certain
>   situations. You can do this in an MFC application by following these
>   steps:
>
> Load the dialog into App Studio and change the OK button identifier
>   from IDOK to something else such as IDC_MYOK. Also, clear the check
>   from Default Button property.
>
> Use ClassWizard to create a message
>   handling function for this button named OnClickedMyOK. This function
>   will be executed when a BN_CLICKED message is received from this
>   button.
>
> In the code for OnClickedMyOK, call the base class version of
>   the OnOK function. Here is an example:

```
void CMyDialog::OnClickedMyOK()
   {
      CDialog::OnOK();
   }
```

Override OnOK for your dialog, and do nothing inside the function. Here is an example:

```
void CMyDialog::OnOK()
   {
   }
```

> Run the program and bring up the dialog. Give focus to a control other
>   than the OK button. Press the RETURN key. Notice that CDialog::OnOK()
>   is never executed.

Comment: Is it correct that this prevents action upon pressing OK but doesn't disable it?

Comment: If you believe the title of the article "How to Disable ...", no ;)

Comment: But I need disable/enable OK button dinamically. That's code:
`bool CSCalcNormCell::OnSelectionChanged( CWnd* pDlg, int type, int page, UINT ctrl_id )
{
DDX_DataBox(pDX.get(), IDC_WORKSHOP_COMBO, ws_code);
if (!CInfactoryPriceAdapter::CanEditPricesForWorkshop( ws_code ))
{
 CWnd* fieldOK = pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK);
 fieldOK->EnableWindow(FALSE);
}
else
{
 CWnd* fieldOK = pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK);
 fieldOK->EnableWindow(TRUE);
}
}`

Comment: In this case I would delete the standard OK button created by default and create my own Button (ID_MYBUTTON). This button you can disable like you already tried ...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem comes from `pDlg` pointer.  When you call `pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK)`, is the dialog already created already?

Make a breakpoint at the line `CWnd* fieldOK = pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK);` and debug into it to see if fieldOK pointer is null or a valid pointer.

That is why I think `mark's answer is very close. You can disable it on`OnInitDialog` or other members of you dialog class after it showed up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the button control has not been created on the interface yet. We do not get the full vision of your problem.

Anyway, you should protect your code from crashing. It is better that your code does nothing than to crash the application. Restructuring it like this avoids the access violation problem due to the NULL pointer:

```
bool CSCalcNormCell::OnSelectionChanged( CWnd* pDlg, int type, int page, UINT ctrl_id ) 
{ 
    DDX_DataBox(pDX.get(), IDC_WORKSHOP_COMBO, ws_code);

    CWnd* fieldOK = pDlg->GetDlgItem(IDOK); 
    if (fieldOK)
    {
        if (!CInfactoryPriceAdapter::CanEditPricesForWorkshop( ws_code )) 
            fieldOK->EnableWindow(FALSE); 
        else
            fieldOK->EnableWindow(TRUE); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load a bitmap for the disable mode of the OK button in LoadBitmaps() function.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This should actually be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the exception, I was also getting it but I found an alternative way of disabling a button using command update handlers, following [darwen's answer](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?314881-CButton-class-how-to-grey-out-a-command-button&p=1033756#post1033756).

This works fine for me:

```cpp
afx_msg void OnUpdateButton(CCmdUI *pCmdUI); 
void CYourClass::OnUpdateButton(CCmdUI *pCmdUI) {
    pCmdUI->Enable(enableButton);
}
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_BUTTON, OnUpdateButton) // On message map
```